# Why would all of the Ender 5 Pro's axis motors (X, Y and Z) stop being able to move (all at once)?

Tags: troubleshooting, creality-ender-5, bigtreetech, skr-mini-e3, 3d-printerworks

I have a Creality Ender 5 Pro which has been working properly for some time. During my last print, the axis motors just suddenly stopped working while the extruder motor continued to work properly.

In fact, when I connect the extruder motor wire to any of the axis motors, they respond correctly (mimicking the extruder motor) but neither works or moves when connected to its own wire(s). As a result the printer does not print anymore.

Here's what I've tried:

- Switching the wires around to check if any motors are damaged (none are).
- Restarting the Creality
- Checking the output on the power source (which is 24 V and about 14 A)
- Checking to make sure all motor wires are connected correctly on the SKR MINI CONTROLLER (all seem fine) and checking that the board is powered.
- All external connections also seem fine.

I'm quite confused why the axis motors would not be working all of a sudden. I'll appreciate your help if you've faced this problem before.

Comment: could be a fried board, bd firmware (if you updated it) or just bad G-code... Does Homing work?

Comment: No... Anything that requires use of axis motors does not work. including homing.

Comment: can you measure the voltage to the motors on a given command?

Comment: @Trish was right. The Creality V1.1.5 board was fried. I replaced it with a BIGTREETECH SKR MINI E3 V2.0 32BIT CONTROLLER. After struggling to find a corresponding firmware for the Ender 5 pro, the axis motors worked correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Creality V1.1.5 board was fried. I replaced it with a BIGTREETECH SKR MINI E3 V2.0 32BIT CONTROLLER. After struggling to find a corresponding firmware for the Ender 5 pro, the axis motors worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, steppers not working can be found when the lines are broken. Often this is an unplugged Stepper, but OP checked that.

That 3 steppers at once failed could indicate a bad firmware update, which OP didn't do. So it is sadly a case of blue smoke from the board. Most likely the stepper drivers are either shortened out or get no signal.

I am sorry, but replacement seems necessary.